# jQuery Fade Out on Scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am using this to fade out a div on scroll but its not working, 600 is the offset of the div. I cant figure out why this is not working.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

 $('.hack').css({
    'transform' : 'translate(0px , ' + wScroll/2  +'%)',
    'opactiy' : 1 - (wScroll/600)
 });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var height = $(window).height();
$('.logo_container, .slogan').css({
    'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ma4na3t/1/)

Comment: Yes it works. So code you write inside that closure using $ will always work.

Comment: I'm sorry i was not clear, i was not talking about the closure.  I was wondering if you could use $(this) instead of $(window) and the closure would still capture the window state, or is $(this) the scroll event that is not associated with the window?

Comment: $(this) is a reference to the member that invokes the current function...

then you can wrap it in the jquery function $() to select it just like you would another selector.

So scrollTop calls a anonymous function so it is not invoked by a referencable member, so it defaults to the $(window) object.